# Mapping to limit length of Array datatype in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

I'm trying to create an elasticsearch Mapping which limits the length of an array datatype to x number of items.

```
mapping = """
{
"mappings": {
        "document": {
            "properties": {
                "pages": {
                    "type": "text"
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
"""
```

in this case, how do I set the "pages" array to have a maximum of 1,000 list items?  Also, is there a way to "ignore" insert errors triggered by ES when this limit has been reached?

Comment: How do you index documents into ES? Can you explain your process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch has no such limits, you'd have to enforce it in your application.

As for ignoring errors look at the `ignore_malformed` option for many fields.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Honza !

I had assumed so eventually ... to expand on your answer, here's how I'm inserting/indexing documents now.  I'm using the script field, combined with the "painless" language to check the field length before indexing the document, like so:

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Honza !

I had assumed so eventually ... to expand on your answer, here's how I'm inserting/indexing documents now:

```
data = {
            "_op_type": "index",
            "_index" : "myIndex",
            "_type" : "document",
            'script' : {
                'inline': 'if(ctx._source.pages.length < 1001){ ctx._source.pages.add(params.page);}',
                'params' : {
                    "page" : "{}".format(item['page'])
                }
            }   
        }
```

I'm using the script field, combined with the "painless" language to check the field length before indexing the document.

Note, I'm using Python Elasticsearch library's bulk helper in the above example, which is why you see the "_op_type" field.